# How to configure message filtering through switches

Tags: c#, trace, system.diagnostics

Here is my code

```
 public static TraceSource TS = new TraceSource("myTraceSrc", SourceLevels.All);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TS.TraceInformation("Hello Information Trace from Main");
        TS.TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, 1, "Hello Error Trace from Main");
```

}

here is config file

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="myTraceSrc" switchName="switch1" >
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="myLocalListener" initializeData="c:\WasteBin\Test.Log"  />
                <add name="consoleListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" name="consoleListener" traceOutputOptions="None" />
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" name="EventListener" traceOutputOptions="None" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
        <add name="switch1" value="all"  />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I want all my messages to go to console and text file but only error should go to events log. How can I set it up using configuration settings?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Try to use logging libraries (Nlog, log4net) for your tasks. They have message filtering and routing.

Comment: I am already considering one to use but are you saying that its not possible to this via TraceSource?

Comment: You can filter TraceSource by Category or EventType in listeners. Check this link [Use TraceSource and Filters with Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993.aspx)

Comment: -1, does not answer the question at all - OP wants to know how to configure his TraceSource listeners not what alternative logging systems exist.